# 1988 T-Bird clicking sound when key is on

Tags: electrical, ford, fuel-system, battery-drain, relay

I accidentally drained my battery so I charged it and went to drive it car died when I went to drive. Now it makes a loud clicking noise and won't stay running. I don't think I put a good charge to begin.

Later I located the noise directly and it's coming from the three fuel relays. The first one is on fuel line by motor and second on passenger side up not way and the third is in my trunk

I replaced fuel filter and two of the relays, made sure the button for ignition switch in trunk, and put an extra ground from the battery

Comment: Please can anyone help?

Comment: If all the relays are clicking, it sounds like you either have a bad battery, or the battery terminals aren't connected correctly. Try cleaning the terminals to ensure they have  a good connection, and if that doesn't work get the batter tested.

Comment: Replace the battery.